# Get Selected Value from select list input array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
let val1 =[];
$('select[name="sub_trimming_id[]"] option:selected').each(function() {
            val1.push($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="sub_trimming_id[' + trimId + ']" id="sub-trim-select-' + trimId + '"></select>
```

From this only return empty array

Comment: Hi, change `$('select[name="sub_trimming_id[]"] option:selected')` to `$('select[name*="sub_trimming_id"] option:selected')`

Comment: Hi This Worked Perfectly Thank u for ur support :)